# Batch - Processing high volume data

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have to process almost 3 million records from the database.

Below is the flow summary:

1. Read two tables (T1, T2)
2. Fetch unique id (IDs) from T1 and fetch attributes from T2 table.
3. There are 3 types of users in the T2 table, A1, A2 and A3.
4. now generate 3 CSV for each user type A1.csv, A2.csv and A3.csv and write the fetched attributes.

I have to perform the above flow in parallel execution and in efficient way. please suggest a suitable Java approach.

Comment: 3M is'nt high volume at all. This is what DBs are for. I don't see the "parallel" here, join two tables with a where, ok, probably you can do the write to CSV in 3 threads. Start and come back with a concrete code question. This can be even done in pure SQL.

Comment: but, I have time for max 1 hour, i can not do this is in sequence.

Comment: I'd try to do this in the database. 3mln records is not that many. Also, if you can't do this in the database in the appropriate time, you most probably won't be able to do this from Java. The database will be your bottleneck anyway.

Comment: Please give more details about the data base approach.

Comment: @Ravish Use normal SQL and database tools to export data as CSV.